# query to find empty spaces only inside a column

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have a column with several empty spaces :

```
'        '
```

is there a query catch columns with several long spaces only ( I am not talking about null)

I tried this but didnt work

```
SELECT *
FROM EX_EMPLOYEE
WHERE  rtrim(ltrim(F_NAME)) = ''
```

Comment: What datatype is `F_NAME`?

Answer (score 1):

Do following instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM EX_EMPLOYEE
WHERE  rtrim(ltrim(F_NAME)) IS NULL
```

Comment: But its not null, however Ill try it

Answer (score 0):

select * from EX_EMPLOYEE where ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(F_NAME,"char"(your_column_lenght),''),"char"(your_column_lenght),''))) = '';

or if that doesnt work, then

where replace(F_NAME,'\x0a','') = '';

I think this is what you need, pls try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You said "several" spaces.  If searching for one or more spaces is close enough to your question, this might work:

```
select count(*) from mytable where mycolumn like "% %"
```

(note, this is searching only for spaces, not tabs)